# Using XY coordinates get the height of coordinates in the view - Android

Tags: java, android

After I touch area in my view, I want to use the XY coordinates to determine where in the view the height of that touch is. So lets say I have a view that is 700 pixels tall, and I touch area in the middle I want to be able to determine the height of the touch in pixel. So for example I touch the middle of the view, I want to return that touched was recorded at 350 pixels high out of the 700 pixels. Is that possible?

```
  myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            float y = event.getY();
            float x = event.getX(); 
            //Using the xy coordinates I want the height of the touch in the view
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)), these methods are returning exactly what you are asking for already (the x-coordinate of the click relative to the `View`), whereas `getRawX()` would instead return the x-coordinate relative to the screen.